# Foregin key field name is followed by _id

Tags: django, django-models

In a model, when a foreign key field is created then Django apparently create another field with the same field name followed by _id.
for example if I have

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    dated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
...
```

Then I will have the following fields available:

```
id,user,user_id,dated
```

I am not sure why this field (`user_id`) was added?

Later I wanted to override my queryset in a class view 
so I was confused which one to use (user field or user_id field)
:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
```

Or

```
def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user=self.request.user.id)
```

I tried both and both worked just fine

My question is:

1) What is the purpose of creating this additional field ?

2) What is the difference between the original foreign key field (user in my case) and user_id field?

3) Will both fields `user` and `user_id` available in the database? what is the point of that?

4) Is the content of `user` and `user_id` identical in each record? if so ,then what the purpose of this additional field that was created automatically by django?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django only creates one column in the database for the foreign key.

The difference between the field and the `_id` attribute it generates is that accessing the field performs a query for the full set of columns from the related table in order to construct the complete related object. If you want the full object, use the field (and probably also use `select_related()` in the initial query to save you from doing N+1 queries).

On the other hand, if all you need is the DB-level value of the foreign key, which is usually the primary key of the related object (and often that is what you want), the `_id` attribute shortcut is there for you and already has the data, because that's what was actually in the foreign key column.

In other words, suppose I have models like this:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()


class ModelB(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    a_instance = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

If you query for a `ModelB`, like `ModelB.objects.get(pk=12)`, you'll get a query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, a_instance_id
FROM your_app.modelb
WHERE id = 12;
```

Notice `a_instance_id` is the name of the column -- it's just a foreign key, all it stores is a pointer to the primary key of a `ModelA` instance. If you just need that primary key, accessing the `a_instance_id` attribute has it already without needing to do another query. If you access the `a_instance` field, though, you get to do another query:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM your_app.modela
WHERE id = (whatever the value of that foreign key was);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation...really helpful...Is there any resource your recommend I can refer to regarding this other than django documents for Models because it doesn't explain any of this... Really appreciate your help